# Change current user authentication during spring test execution

Tags: java, authentication, testing

In Java tests, `@WithMockUser` initialize the current user to a fake user. **How to modify this user inside my test method** (so after the mocked user is created) ?

Example

```java
@Test
@WithMockUser(roles = {"USER"})
void myTest() {
    // add to the current user the "ADMIN" role
}
```

The final aim is to use `@ParameterizedTest` to run a test one time per authentication provided in parameter (for example: run the same test for "ADMIN" user, for "USER" user and for "MANAGER" user).

I've tried this:

```java
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));

Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password", authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

But the spring context seems to not reload, so my current user has no "ADMIN" role if I check it after those lines.